# Ruby on Rails error when testing for validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

So I am currently following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBfD7ZPnpo8&index=5&list=PLY_TsbWXHC0IaIWdnQwkLRdg9pXsyY_pW) and on the 5th episode I have followed the directions and updated the syntax for Rails 4.1.6 that I am using with the new Gems. My code is on [Github](https://github.com/nikeshashar/saas)

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'pg'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'devise'

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'warden'
end
```

My spec/models/user_spec.rb has the following:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Account do 

  describe 'validations' do 
    it { should validate_presence_of (:name)}
    it { should validate_presence_of (:email)}
    it { should validate_presence_of (:password)}
  end

  describe 'associations' do 
  end

end
```

My app/models/user.rb has:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

And when running RSpec I get the following errors:

```
Account
  validations
    should require name to be set (FAILED - 1)
    should require email to be set (FAILED - 2)
    should require password to be set (FAILED - 3)

Failures:

  1) Account validations should require name to be set
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of (:name)}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `name=' for #<Account:0x00000108092050>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Account validations should require email to be set
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of (:email)}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `email=' for #<Account:0x00000108088640>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Account validations should require password to be set
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of (:password)}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `password=' for #<Account:0x00000108079af0>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Been stuck on this for a while now and cannot figure out what else I need to check. Any ideas would be a great help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're testing Account, when those fields are actually on the User model.  See your schema here: https://github.com/nikeshashar/saas/blob/master/db/schema.rb

As a recommendation, put those validation checks in User, and then in the rspec Account tests, test that the account has an owner. So, account.owner should have those attributes and validate the same as a user.